# Unexpected error in IBM MFPF library - why is that?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

Time to time I get reports in Crashlytics with some unexpected error in Android mobile application with library 8.0.2019072508. This bug also was in previous versions of the library. Does anyone know how to fix it and prevent the application crash?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.AssertionError: This should never be reached
       at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider + 2666(Cipher.java:2666)
       at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations + 2556(Cipher.java:2556)
       at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider + 2475(Cipher.java:2475)
       at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider + 566(Cipher.java:566)
       at javax.crypto.Cipher.init + 973(Cipher.java:973)
       at javax.crypto.Cipher.init + 908(Cipher.java:908)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.bc.BcKeyStoreSpi.makePBECipher + 476(BcKeyStoreSpi.java:476)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.bc.BcKeyStoreSpi$StoreEntry.getObject + 235(BcKeyStoreSpi.java:235)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.bc.BcKeyStoreSpi.engineGetKey + 610(BcKeyStoreSpi.java:610)
       at java.security.KeyStoreSpi.engineGetEntry + 516(KeyStoreSpi.java:516)
       at java.security.KeyStore.getEntry + 1621(KeyStore.java:1621)
       at com.worklight.common.security.WLDeviceAuthManager.getSecretKeyEntry + 355(WLDeviceAuthManager.java:355)
       at com.worklight.common.security.WLDeviceAuthManager.getDeviceUUID + 167(WLDeviceAuthManager.java:167)
       at com.worklight.wlclient.OkHttpInterceptor.intercept + 83(OkHttpInterceptor.java:83)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed + 147(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed + 121(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain + 200(RealCall.java:200)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute + 147(RealCall.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run + 32(NamedRunnable.java:32)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker + 1162(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run + 636(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at java.lang.Thread.run + 764(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Are you using JSONStore?

Comment: What is your version of Android and the version of your iFix ? Are you perhaps encountering this behaviour - https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2018/08/06/IBM-MobileFirst-Android-Pie/#mobilefirst-v80-apps ?

Comment: @Keerthi no, we don't use JSONStore

Comment: @Srik The bug happens from time to time on android 7 and android 8. What is iFix, I supposed we don't use it?

Comment: This requires a more detailed investigation. Please open a case with IBM. Also provide more details on when does the error occur and any pattern you're seeing